# What are the altitudes for the various altitude record contracts?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In career mode, you have the option of taking on a number of altitude record contracts, which are simply to get a rocket to a given altitude.  However they're presented one at a time, and if you pass the record for the next contract, you won't be offered it; instead you'll get the one after that.  While this might not seem like a big deal, it means potentially missing out on funds, science, and reputation early in the game, generally when you need it the most, especially when playing on hard mode.

So what are the various altitudes for which I can get an altitude record contract?

Comment: Pretty annoying that. Got to 11 km, unlocked coupler. Great, let's stack 3 of those trashcans. Solid boosters are cheap after all. I think I hit 360 km with that setup o_O

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the somewhat aggressive "technique" of "aim down once I reach the altitude objective" I can confirm Lex's answer.

The altitude record contracts are as follows:

1. 05km
2. 11km
3. 22km
4. 33km
5. 56km
6. Escape the atmosphere

The attached image shows all of them in the contract archives, I'd like to back this up with a Wiki Link however it's been down all day

[image: Contracts Screen]

Comment: The wiki being down is why I asked.

Comment: Well I've been through the GameData directory, can't seem to find the contract definitions. Short of going through the source code this is the closest we'll get. Even if the Wiki is up I don't know how useful it will be, from what I remember it discusses the core concepts of the contract system but doesn't list specific contracts because these fixed parameter contracts are quite a small part of the contract system.

Comment: @MBraedley Yea, I just checked, wiki is back up, but its a broad outline, nothing specific. Nothing on the forums with obvious search terms either. Though I can assure you my test flights (which the screen shot is from) are sound, I never went more than a few meters over each objective to ensure I didn't miss any.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly: 5500m, 11000m, 22000m, 33000m and 55000m. After that, you get to explore the space.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could provide an authoritative source instead of just relying on your memory.